# This kernel is trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M_0,\ldots,M_N$ be all the monomials of degree $d$ in the $n+1$ variables $x_0,\ldots,x_n$, where $N=C_{n+d,n}-1$.

Let $\theta:k[y_0,\ldots,y_N]\to k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ be the homomorphism defined by sending $y_i$ to the monomial $M_i$.

Then $\ker\theta$ is just the trivial one? I'm trying to understand how this kernel looks like and why it's homogeneous.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

For example, if $d=1$ and $y_0\mapsto M_0=x_0$, $y_1\mapsto M_1=x_0$ then $y_0-y_1\in ker\theta$. Am I right? if yes $Ker\theta$ is homogeneous?

Comment: $(x_0x_1)(x_2x_3)=(x_0x_2)(x_1x_3)$. The kernel is homogeneous since $\theta$ is.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg yes, thanks

Comment: Dear user42912,I'm afraid you are not right: your polynomials are neither  homogeneous nor of the same degree ...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg arbitrary $d\gt 0$

Comment: Dear user42912, $x_0^3x_1$ is not of arbitrary degree...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I understood what do you mean, I will edit again

Comment: ...and $y_0-y_1^3y_2$ is not homogeneous...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg my example was wrong because of the degree of the $M_I$, I'm having problems to find a non-trivial element of the kernel.

Comment: @user what means $\theta$ be homogeneous?

Answer (score 2):

There is no injective $k$-algebra  morphism  $k[y_0,...,y_N]\hookrightarrow k[x_0,...,x_n]$ if $ N \gt n$, because it would induce a (necessarily injective) morphism of $k$-extension fields  $k(y_0,...,y_N)\hookrightarrow k(x_0,...,x_n)$.
  This is impossible since the transcendence degrees of the fields are  $N\gt n$.
So, no, $\text {ker} \:\theta$ is not trivial.

Algebraic geometers have a lot to say about your morphism: google *Veronese morphism*.